# Solving $y'(t) = \frac{1}{2}y''(2y(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

What is the class of solutions for the differential equation (with $t \in \mathbb{R}$):

$$y'(t) = \frac{1}{2}y''(2y(t))?$$

In the previous equation, the second derivative of $y$ is evaluated in $2y(t)$ (it is *not* the multiplication of $y''(t)$ with $y(t)$).

Generally, I would be interested in references about this kind of differential equations involving recurrence.

Comment: Vladimir Arnold would bristle at your tagging this a differential equation.

Comment: To me, it's a perfectly respectable differential equation. It doesn't have to be used for only classical mechanics to be a valid differential equation.

Comment: As for tackling this, the first thing that pops into my head is making a substitution.

Comment: According to the most general definition I have seen adopted, namely as an object of the form $F(x,y,y',y'')=0$, this does not qualify as a differential equation. What is the natural context for such functional-differential equation?

Comment: What is the background of this equation?